# Android: way of getting the user's countrycode without using any permissions that need to be actively requested?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-location, android-6.0-marshmallow, country-codes

I want to get a user's country code without using any permissions that need to be actively requested under android M. For example, if the user were located in China I would want to get back CH. I don't want to use "dangerous" permissions for this - neither `read_phone_state` to go through the `TelephonyManager`, nor location in order to try to guess based on his GPS. Is there a way to do this and if so, how?

I've tried using the following code but it's prone to failure if the user sets his language settings separate from his country (e.g. user in India sets his phone to English_US):

```
Resources r = paramContext.getResources();
Configuration config = r.getConfiguration();
Locale currentLocale = config.locale;
Log.d("TAG", "Country: " + currentLocale.getCountry());
```

Comment: Which is exactly the error message you are getting and which instruction is generating it?

Comment: Please explain **precisely** what "a user's countrycode" is. For example, if a US citizen using a UK SIM card is in Sweden, what is that user's "countrycode"?

Comment: @CommonsWare - in the example that you provided it would be the swedish countrycode (I believe "SE"). The sim/citizenship isn't what I'm looking for. I want the countrycode so that I can correctly format the phone number

Comment: I've used [TelephonyManager.getSimCountryIso()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSimCountryIso()) and it seems to work fine. It doesn't require dangerous permissions. Note that it returns the information from the SIM card, so in CommonsWare's example will probably return "UK", not "SE".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way you can determine the user's physical location programmatically requires a `dangerous` permission.

If you do not want to ask the user for the permission, then ask the user for the user's location.

> I've tried using the following code

That code has nothing to do with the user's physical location.

Answer (score 5):

All methods that allow to determine the user's current location with a certain confidence level are marked as dangerous.

That being said, there are several methods that are not as reliable, but might be acceptable for you:

1. locale:

   - precondition: locale can be mapped to a single country
   - source of errors: user is abroad
   - source of errors: user is foreigner
   - source of errors: bad l10n quality for the country
2. `TelephonyManager.getSimCountryIso()`

   - precondition: needs an active SIM card
   - source of errors: user is abroad
   - source of errors: user bought SIM card from abroad
3. Looking up the location via GeoIP database

   - precondition: needs an active internet connection
   - source of errors: database has wrong mapping for the IP address
   - source of errors: active VPN network
4. asking the user for his country

   - precondition: application workflow allows user input
   - source of errors: input mistakes
   - source of errors: information is stale because user did not update the information
   - source of errors: user maliciously enters wrong information